# Airflow database reset after system reboot

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

I have set up an Apache Airflow instance without any further configuration (Sequential Executor and the SQLLiteDB) on a plain EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 free instance. Everything is working as expected until I restart the system. Once the system is restarted, I am not able to restart the web server anymore. When I navigate to http://myec2instanceip:8080 the server is not showing up.

When I am trying to list the airflow processes after I restart the server by using `sudo ps -ax | grep airflow`, the web server process is not listed.

I figured out that after manually deleting the `airflow-scheduler.pid` and `airflow-webserver-monitor.pid` in the airflow home directory, I can successfully rerun `airflow webserver -p 8080 -D` and `airflow scheduler -D`.
I cannot really figure out why this behaviour actually occurs and I want to figure out how I can establish a stable version even after rebooting the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting your machine will kill the processes.
if you would like it to start after reboot, you could configure and run ariflow in a service:
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-with-systemd.html